# Get data by week laravel for graph

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm having a problem querying data for a graph, which I expect to get something like this

```
[count_week_1, count_week_2, count_week_3, count_week_4]
```

but i don't know how to get it, someone help me

table product

```
+-----+------+---------------------+
| id  | name | created_at          |
+-----+------+---------------------+
| 1   | test | 2021-06-1 00:00:00  |
+-----+------+---------------------+
|                ...               |
+-----+------+---------------------+
| 297 | test | 2021-06-30 00:00:00 |
+-----+------+---------------------+
```

Comment: What is your database structure? Which data is aggretated via count?

Comment: all the data in the table

Answer (score 0):

Using Laravel's query builder, your code would look something like that:

```
DB::table('product')
    ->selectRaw('COUNT(id) AS count_week')
    ->groupByRaw('DATEPART(weekday, created_at)')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('count_week');
```

Of course, if you have a model, it'll look more like this:

```
Product::selectRaw('COUNT(id) AS count_week')
    ->groupByRaw('DATEPART(weekday, created_at)')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('count_week');
```

Comment: i found an error "Unknown column 'DATEPART(weekday, created_at)' in 'group statement'"

Comment: i just want to take all the data of this month and calculate all the data by week
for example like this
[24, 312, 23, 12]

Comment: I know, what you want. This is what my answer is intended to reflect.

Comment: Besides that, I fixed my answer.

Comment: @richoandika Have you checked my updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        $data[] = Product::whereBetween(
            'created_at',
            [Carbon::now()->subWeek($i + 1)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), Carbon::now()->subWeek($i)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]
        )->get()->count();
    }
    return json_encode(array_reverse($data));
```